# List is separating letters when saving to a file

Tags: python, list

Every time I run my code and input data it comes out like this. (['d', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r']), How do I combine it into a single word?

```
    time = 0
    times = int(input('How many months do you want to save?'))
    for time in range(times):
        if time <= times:
            time = time + 1
            month = input('What is your favorite month?')
            list1 = list(month)
            save_data = open('month.text','a')
            save_data.write('\r\n')
            save_data.write(str(list1))
            save_data.close()
```

Comment: This is most likely a simple fix, but i have been searching about 20 minutes for an. answer and found none.

Comment: You don't have to do `list1 = list(month)` in the first place

Comment: As @taras says, you are creating the list with list(month)

Comment: Thank you all that have helped, it is working correctly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the `month` directly

```
    time = 0
    times = int(input('How many months do you want to save?'))
    for time in range(times):
        if time <= times:
            time = time + 1
            month = input('What is your favorite month?')
            save_data = open('month.text','a')
            save_data.write('\r\n')
            save_data.write(month)
            save_data.close()
```